# JButton buttons not showing up in JPanel from extended class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

The homework expands on our previous lab where we made a really basic calculator. We are supposed to add some buttons pow, sqrt, pct, and log.

I extended from my BasicCalculator.java file but the buttons I added in my new class are not being added but the setBackground colors are working perfectly fine. so why are the buttons added in the same method not being added?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends BasicCalculator
{
// Attributes
protected JButton pow, sqr, pct, log;
// Constructors
public Calculator()
{
    super();
}
// Methods
public void createModifiedUserInterface()
{
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() );
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    createUserInterface();
    pow = new JButton("^");
    sqr = new JButton("sqr");
    pct = new JButton("pct");
    log = new JButton("log");

    keyPad.add(pow);
    keyPad.add(sqr);
    keyPad.add(log);
    keyPad.add(pct);

    displayBox.setHorizontalAlignment(displayBox.RIGHT);
    displayBox.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    clr.setBackground(Color.RED);
    com.setBackground(Color.GREEN);        
    b0.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b5.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b6.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b7.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b8.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b9.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    bd.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    add.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    sub.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    mul.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    div.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    mod.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    pow.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    sqr.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    log.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    pct.setBackground(Color.PINK);

    pow.addActionListener(this);
    sqr.addActionListener(this);
    log.addActionListener(this);
    pct.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    displayBox.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    super.actionPerformed(e);
    if (e.getSource() == pow)
    {
        operator = '^';
        operand1 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
        displayBox.setText("");
    }
    if (e.getSource() == sqr)
    {
        operand1 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
        displayBox.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        displayBox.setText(new Double(Math.sqrt(operand1)).toString());
    }
    if (e.getSource() == log)
    {
        operand1 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
        displayBox.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        displayBox.setText(new Double(Math.log(operand1)).toString());
    }
    if (e.getSource() == pct)
    {
        operand1 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
        displayBox.setBackground(Color.GREEN);            
        displayBox.setText(new Double(operand1 * 100).toString());
    }
}

public void calculate()
{
    displayBox.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    super. calculate();

    if (operator == '^')
    {
        displayBox.setText(new Double(Math.pow(operand1, operand2)).toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Calculator mine = new Calculator();
    mine.createModifiedUserInterface(); 
}

}
```

here is the code that is in the 'BasicCalculator.java' file even though it's pretty clunky.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BasicCalculator implements ActionListener
{
//attributes
protected double operand1, operand2;
protected char operator;
protected JFrame calWin;
protected JTextField displayBox;
protected JPanel keyPad;
protected JButton b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, dot;
protected JButton add, sub, mul, div, mod, com, clr;

//constructors
public BasicCalculator() 
{
    clean();
}

//methods
public void clean()
{
    operand1 = 0;
    operand2 = 0;
    operator = ' ';

}

public void createUserInterface()
{
    calWin = new JFrame("Calculator");
    displayBox = new JTextField(20);
    keyPad = new JPanel();
    b0 = new JButton("0");
    b1 = new JButton("1");
    b2 = new JButton("2");
    b3 = new JButton("3");
    b4 = new JButton("4");
    b5 = new JButton("5");
    b6 = new JButton("6");
    b7 = new JButton("7");
    b8 = new JButton("8");
    b9 = new JButton("9");
    dot = new JButton(".");
    add = new JButton("+");
    sub = new JButton("-");
    mul = new JButton("*");
    div = new JButton("/");
    mod = new JButton("%");
    com = new JButton("=");
    clr = new JButton("C");

    keyPad.add(displayBox);
    keyPad.add(b0);
    keyPad.add(b1);
    keyPad.add(b2);
    keyPad.add(b3);
    keyPad.add(b4);
    keyPad.add(b5);
    keyPad.add(b6);
    keyPad.add(b7);
    keyPad.add(b8);
    keyPad.add(b9);
    keyPad.add(dot);
    keyPad.add(add);
    keyPad.add(sub);
    keyPad.add(mul);
    keyPad.add(div);
    keyPad.add(mod);
    keyPad.add(com);
    keyPad.add(clr);
    calWin.getContentPane().add(keyPad);
    calWin.setSize(300, 300);
    calWin.setVisible(true);
    calWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    b0.addActionListener(this);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    b4.addActionListener(this);
    b5.addActionListener(this);
    b6.addActionListener(this);
    b7.addActionListener(this);
    b8.addActionListener(this);
    b9.addActionListener(this);
    dot.addActionListener(this);
    add.addActionListener(this);
    sub.addActionListener(this);
    mul.addActionListener(this);
    div.addActionListener(this);
    mod.addActionListener(this);
    com.addActionListener(this);
    clr.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == b0)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "0");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == b1)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "1");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == b2)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "2");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == b3)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "3");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == b4)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "4");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == b5)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "5");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == b6)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "6");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == b7)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "7");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == b8)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "8");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == b9)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + "9");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == dot)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().contains("+") && operator == '+' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("-") && operator == '-' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("/") && operator == '/' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("*") && operator == '*' || 
           displayBox.getText().contains("%") && operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("");
        }
        displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText() + ".");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == add)
    {
        operator = '+';
        operand1 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
        displayBox.setText("+ ");
    }
            if(e.getSource() == sub)
    {
        if(displayBox.getText().trim().equals("") || 
           operator == '+' ||
           operator == '-' ||
           operator == '/' ||
           operator == '*' ||
           operator == '%')
        {
            displayBox.setText("-");
        }
        else
        {
            operator = '-';
            operand1 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
            displayBox.setText("- ");
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == div)
    {
        operator = '/';
        operand1 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
        displayBox.setText("/ ");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == mul)
    {
        operator = '*';
        operand1 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
        displayBox.setText("* ");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == mod)
    {
        operator = '%';
        operand1 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
        displayBox.setText("% ");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == clr)
    {
        displayBox.setText("");
        clean();
    }
    if(e.getSource() == com)
    {
        operand2 = new Double(displayBox.getText()).doubleValue();
        calculate();
    }
}

public void calculate()
{
    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+': displayBox.setText(new Double(operand1 + operand2).toString()); break;
        case '-': displayBox.setText(new Double(operand1 - operand2).toString()); break;    
        case '*': displayBox.setText(new Double(operand1 * operand2).toString()); break;  
        case '/': displayBox.setText(new Double(operand1 / operand2).toString()); break;   
        case '%': displayBox.setText(new Double(operand1 % operand2).toString()); break;    
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Try using `calWin.pack()` instead of `calWin.setSize(300, 300)`

Comment: wow, for some reason I had to repost this because 1 guy commented that it was a repost of question about setBackground not working for JButton because he clearly didn't read the question. i know it's kind of confusing but I have been researching and trying to figure out what im doing wrong for 3 hours already theres no reason for a negative vote. seriously.

Comment: Your question is confusing..."added in my new class are not being added but the **color style** we are supposed to add is being added" - I have no idea what the question is about any more...

Comment: calWin.pack() just made everything into one really long window.

Comment: Cause you're using `FlowLayout` as your default layout for your buttons, not a great choice, I'd be using a [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) instead

Comment: ok i will reword. basically the setBackground colors i have added to the buttons from BasicCalculator.java work perfectly fine. but the buttons added within the same method are not being added and I do not know why.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the help the issue isn't the window it is the buttons not showing up but only the buttons from the createModifiedUserInterface() method are not showing up. sorry it was so confusing. but I appreciate the response.

Comment: Your window's to small and the layout manager is pushing them outside of the visible area...see answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a layout manager that is more capable of meeting your needs, something like a `GridLayout`...

[image]

In your `BasicCalculator` class, change the `keyPad` to use a `GridLayout` and pack the window.

```
keyPad = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
//...
calWin.getContentPane().add(keyPad);
```

Comment: wow that's weird that they show up with the gridlayout. that fixed it props for answering a confusing question. I really appreciate it!